# How to trigger event for chapter markers when playing a quicktime movie?

Tags: iphone, ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller, quicktime, movie

I'm trying to create an iPad app where i need to playback a quicktime movie which contains some chapter markers. When each marker is reached i need a small overlay to be shown on top of the video.
Is there a way to trigger an event/function each time a marker is reached? And if so, how?

I'm not interested in having to develop an entire movieplayer with codec handling from scratch, since this is out of my comfortzone - So I'm hoping this is possible using MPMoviePlayer or something similar.

Any help is greatly appreciated! :)

Comment: So..what was the solution u got Milk78??

Comment: I didn't find a solution and changes in the project meant that I haven't pursued the solution further. But I'm still very interested in finding a good solution for this :)

Answer (score 0):

Register to receive the following notification:

```
#define MPAVControllerTimeDidJumpNotification @"MPAVControllerTimeDidJumpNotification"

[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(handleTimeChanged:) name:MPAVControllerTimeDidJumpNotification object:nil];

-(void)handleTimeChanged:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    static int i = 0;
    NSDictionary * userInfo = notification.userInfo;
    int lastPositionInSeconds = [[userInfo valueForKey:@"MPAVControllerTimeParameter"] intValue];
    if(lastPositionInSeconds > markers[i])
    {
         i++;
         [self showOverlay: i];
    }
}
```

Also register to receive MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification notification to stop listening for the MPAVControllerTimeDidJumpNotification notification.

Comment: That does look like a private API to me, at least I haven't found that notification in the docs (and you wouldn't need to #define it if it were "official").

Comment: If it's a private API I can't use it - The app will be rejected. Also, this looks like it will trigger if i specifically jump to a chapter - Thats not what i need. The movie will play from start to finish without any jumping, but when i get to a chapter marker I need to show an overlay so somehow I need to trigger an event when the playback hit a marker.